# No mobile internet connection hs3114

Tags: networking, internet

I have the HP Probook 650 G2 with the hs3114 mobile internet adapter. The software (Ubuntu 18.04) already finds the board (I already found how to find them). I also tried the Modem Manager form the Ubuntu software store but it says that I am not connectet. When I click on the connect button a notification says that it did not work (The same in the network manager). Does anyone knows what the problem is?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi R.Puch. Do you see "Mobile Broadband" in the system menu? (More information on the [Ubuntu Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-mobile.html)

Comment: yes i see it in the system menu